# SSIS Error with Excel Connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have a problem with an SSIS job all of a sudden complaining about an excel connection. The only thing that has happened is a windows update which i would assume is the cause.

The excel connection is with in a data flow task, and there are actually 8 connections that open the same excel file but different wok sheets withing the file and union all them together into a SS table.

Have searched high and low for answers, and have my usual steps to try fix this, but can't solve this one, so just after any ideas.

One interesting thing is it works when running from my desktop using visual studio 2010 but not on the ssis server .

my usual methods which have not worked are.

1.) set delay validation to false for excel connection

2.) set delay validation to false for the data flow task which houses the error.

3.) set maximum concurrent tasks for 1.

4.) make sure and verify job running at 32 bit.

> Error: 0xC0202009 at LoadReportingTables_POC, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unexpected error from external database driver (1).".
>   Error: 0xC020801C at PnLExtract, Aviation [92]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with

also get this

> Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Unexpected error from external database driver (1).".

Comment: So, you're trying to open an Excel XLS file from the SSIS Server, and you get the error above, but you can open the same file from Visual Studio without a problem.  Is that correct?  Were these files working before and stopped working?   Did you notice that the error mentions a **Driver Problem**?

Comment: when i run the job from visual studio on the ssis server it has the error, but when run locally it is fine. There is an error mentioning driver which i adeed above. I have seen this error many times, but my usual methods havent fixed it.

Comment: Is JET installed on the server?  Be advised that Microsoft does not support using JET in this way - there's a replacement, but the name escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should download the Microsoft Access Database Engine to solve this problem.

**Download Links:**

- **2016:** https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920
- **2010:** https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: download to the SSIS server, that is.  Local environment that doesn't have the error already has it.